# Code Mirror with Firebase mark text

Tags: codemirror, firepad

I am trying to understand Code Mirror which I am using with [FirePad](https://firepad.io/) - I get it all working, but now I want to do something a bit more 'exciting'.

I am looking to markText to make it readOnly but I cannot find out anywhere how to actually do it.  My need is to load the editor, and preset with a template (best way to describe it) so that the template has some preset readOnly text and users then update the textarea after the read only text i.e. it can't be deleted/over written

Example (template being inserted into the FirePad):

```
<div><strong>Note</strong></div><br/>
<div>Type text in here</div><br/>
<div><strong>What has been achieved since last session</strong></div><br/>
<div>Type text in here</div><br/>
```

in this example people should be able to type in the area/s marked 'type text here'.

To call the text editor I use this:

```
var firepadRef = new Firebase('https://XXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/test');
var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('someID'), { lineWrapping: true });
var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef, codeMirror, { richTextToolbar: true, richTextShortcuts: true });
```

any ideas?

Comment: Note that 'readOnly' will be "enforced" client-side, savvy users can easily circumvent it.

Comment: Hi Beni - aware of that, but the situation this is required it is not for 'open abuse' it is more to layout a template that 'employees' should follow